# Using search scoring to determine controller behaviour (tire/elasticsearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm new to [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org) and [tire](https://github.com/karmi/tire), and I'm struggling to work out how to expose the scores of the search results.

Given a particular query string, I want to be able to do the following:

- If there are multiple 'good' results (highly scored) **=>** Send the user to page A (select between them)
- If there is one 'good' results **=>** Send the user to page B (proceed using the item found)
- If there are no 'good' results **=>** Send the user to page C (drop-off page)

Is it possible to do this with tire? If so, how?

Comment: Why not just check the number of results returned, for > 1, 1 and 0?
Also what constitutes a 'good' result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. The routing logic is quite simple: just have a look how many results are returned and what is their score (the `_score` property).

The problem is, how would you know the result is "good". Obviously, you know the score, but the tricky part is calculating or estimating what's a good score. For example, you can use the [`custom_score`](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/custom_score_queries_test.rb) or the [`boosting`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/boosting-query.html) query to manipulate the score, but how you'll know what's the "good" value?